# i cant understand remove()'s time complexity in python is O(n)

Tags: python, list

hi there now i'm studing Python but i really dont understand `remove()`'s time complexity..
i thought it's O(n^2)

if i use `A.remove(X)`
first of all, it's going to search X in A -> O(n)
then, delete X and all items after X are going to move left -> O(n)
so that time complexity is O(n^2)

if you find something's wrong, could you explain?

Comment: `if i use A.remove(X) first of all, it's going to search X in A -> O(n) then, delete X and all items after X are going to move left -> O(n) so that time complexity is O(n^2)` No That would be `2n` which is `O(n)`. You are doing 1 O(n) operation to find the element, and then 1 O(n) operation to shift left. You're not doing n O(n) operations.

Comment: As @JimNilsson has explained its time complexity is ```O(2n) ~ O(n)```. I should mention that the worst time complexity is ```O(2n)``` when the item is located at the end of they array. But if the item is located in first part or any part but not at the end, its time complexity would be less than ```O(n)```

Comment: thanks Jim and Orca!!! i can understand now clearly!!

i misunderstood what remove() work is searching X in A then shifting items after x 

thanks bro~ have nice day!!